# How to correctly develop within a feature branch that spans months

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-rebase

I'm in the current situation that I have to develop a feature for an existing, still under heavy development, project.

The feature should only be merged with the master branch when it is completely done. However, the development of the new feature will take around 3-4 months.

So my workflow right now is roughly:

1. Develop on my feature branch (`git add -u`)
2. commit and push to feature branch (`git commit && git push`)
3. Checkout and pull master (`git checkout master && git pull`)
4. Checkout feature branch and merge with master every day (`git checkout feature-branch && git merge master`); Here I pray to the Git overlord that I don't get nasty merge conflicts
5. Rinse and repeat 1-4

First of all, is this approach the 'correct' way (if there is such a thing as correct)? Or is `git rebase` the preferred method here to get a linear history?

What really bugs me is the way the log looks like:

[image: Example git log]

And obviously the log will only get wider and wider by the day, until one day I merge the feature branch into the master branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for this situation you would more commonly use a `rebase` workflow.  That is, instead of repeatedly merging in the changes from the master branch, you would rebase your branch on master periodically.

The end result is the same (and you will still need to resolve conflicts if the master branch has changes to the same code that you've been editing), but the end result is that your branch always appears to branch off the tip of the `master` branch, rather than some point in the distant path, and the resulting history is substantially cleaner.

The workflow would look something like:

1. Develop on your feature branch
2. commit your changes
3. periodically refresh your local copy of the `master` branch (`git
   remote update`)
4. Rebase on master (`git rebase origin/master`)
5. Rinse and repeat

You can `git push` the changes on your branch as you like, although
note that after a rebase you need `git push -f` because you have now
changed the history of your branch.

When you're all done and ready to merge, you:

1. git checkout master
2. git pull
3. git merge your-feature-branch
4. git push

[This essay](http://kensheedlo.com/essays/why-you-should-use-a-rebase-workflow/) seems to be a good overview of the workflow.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought as well. Just to make sure though: If I rebase then *all* my commits in the feature branch will be at the tip of the master branch? So by the time I merge the feature into master all my commits in the feature branch will be on top? So it would look like: master --> {my 400 commits}?

Comment: Ok, my questions were answered in the link you provided. I guess the only thing I don't like about this approach is that it rewrites the history. So will the timestamps always be starting at that of the last commit on the master branch?

Comment: Rebasing will preserve the timestamp of your commits.